# Python program, taking an input from the user, convert miles to kilometers

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code I have so far, when I run it I get a syntax error and I don't know why

```
#input from the user 
def main()
miles = float(input("Enter a distance in miles: "))


conv_fac = 1.609 #conversion factor 

#calculating how many kilometers 
kilometers = miles * conv_fac


print("The distance in kilometers is: ", kilometers)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't add a `:` sign after the `main()` function
should be

```
#input from the user 
def main():
    miles = float(input("Enter a distance in miles: "))
    conv_fac = 1.609 #conversion factor 
    #calculating how many kilometers 
    kilometers = miles * conv_fac
    print("The distance in kilometers is: ", kilometers)

main()
```

here is result:

[image]

Comment: yes, that's the only error am seeing, am assuming the indentation is okay in the real code.

Comment: when the code runs, it just spits back the same number...any thought? for example if you enter 34 it just outputs 34 again

Comment: its works, when i tried it, not sure what the problem is exactly, am suspecting, there is no proper indentation some where in the code. you can just copy and paste the one i wrote and check it

Comment: @MuyideIbukun - I gave you an upvote for clearly answering this question correctly. Seems like Tom does not appreciate the effort people give to answer his questions for free. He did the same to me: [ansible-playbook-not-displaying-output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281331/ansible-playbook-not-displaying-output)

Answer (score -1):

```
def convert_to_miles(miles):                                                         
    return miles * 1.6                                                         

print convert_to_miles(miles)
```

Comment: Do not post code only answer. Please [edit] the answer and add some explanation.